# Unix scripting in bash to search logs and return a specific part of a specific log file

Tags: bash, scripting, redhat

Dare I say it, I am mainly a Windows person (please don't shoot me down too soon), although I have played around in Linux in the past (mostly command line). 
I have a process I have to go through once in a while which is in essence searching all log files in a directory (and sub directories) for a certain filename and then getting something out of said log file.

My first step is

```
grep -Ril <filename or Partial filename you are looking for> log/*.log
```

From that I have the log filename and I `vi` that to find where it occurs. 
To clarify: that `grep` is looking through all log files seeing if the filename after the `-Ril` occurs within them.

```
vi log/<log filename>
/<filename or Partial filename you are looking for>
```

I do `j` a couple of times to find CDATA, and then I have a URL I need to extract, then in `putty` do a select, copy and paste it into a browser.
Then I quit `vi` without saving.

---

```
FRED1 triggered at Mon Aug 31 14:09:31 NZST 2015 with incoming file /u03/incoming/fred/Fred.2
Fred.2
start grep
end grep
Renamed to Fred.2.20150831140931

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <runResponse><runReturn><item><name>runId</name><value>1703775</value></item><item><name>runHistoryId</name><value>1703775</value></item><item><name>runReportUrl</name><value>https://<Servername>:<port and path>b1a&amp;sp=l0&amp;sp=l1703775&amp;sp=l1703775</value></item><item><name>displayRunReportUrl</name><value><![CDATA[https://<Servername>:<port and path2>&sp=l1703775&sp=l1703775]]></value></item><item><name>runStartTime</name><value>08/31/15 14:09</value></item><item><name>flowResponse</name><value></value></item><item><name>flowResult</name><value></value></item><item><name>flowReturnCode</name><value>Not a Return</value></item></runReturn></runResponse>
    filePath=/u03/incoming/fred&fileName=Fred.2.20150831140931&team=dps&direction=incoming&size=31108&time=Aug 31 14:09&fts=nzlssftsd01

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FRED1 triggered at Mon Aug 31 14:09:31 NZST 2015 with incoming file /u03/incoming/fred/Fred.3
Fred.3
start grep
end grep
Renamed to Fred.3.20150999999999

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <runResponse><runReturn><item><name>runId</name><value>1703775</value></item><item><name>runHistoryId</name><value>1703775</value></item><item><name>runReportUrl</name><value>https://<Servername>:<port and path>b1a&amp;sp=l0&amp;sp=l999999&amp;sp=l9999999</value></item><item><name>displayRunReportUrl</name><value><![CDATA[https://<Servername>:<port and path2>&sp=l999999&sp=l999999]]></value></item><item><name>runStartTime</name><value>08/31/15 14:09</value></item><item><name>flowResponse</name><value></value></item><item><name>flowResult</name><value></value></item><item><name>flowReturnCode</name><value>Not a Return</value></item></runReturn></runResponse>
    filePath=/u03/incoming/fred&fileName=Fred.3.20150999999999&team=dps&direction=incoming&size=31108&time=Aug 31 14:09&fts=nzlssftsd01
```

What I want to grab is the URL in `CDATA[https://<Servername>:<port and path2>&sp=l999999&sp=l999999]` for `Fred.3.20150999999999` indicated by the line `Renamed to Fred.3.20150999999999`.

Is this possible? (And I do apologise by the XML formatting, but it is exactly as it is in the log file.)

Thanks in advance,
Tel

Comment: The snippet of the log I have pasted is only one part.
There are multiple entries like that so we need to find the one associated with the filename to extract. (In the above snippet the filename would be Fred.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n 's@\(.*CDATA\[\)\(.*\)\(\]\].*\)@\2@p'  <logfile>
```

-n suppress automatic printing of pattern space

@ - as sed pattern delimiter

( ) - grouping the patterns

\2 - second pattern

p - print

**Update - grep file pattern **

```
grep -Ril <filename or Partial filename you are looking for> log/*.log | xargs sed -n "/<pattern>/,/filePath=/p" | sed -n 's@\(.*CDATA\[\)\(.*\)\(\]\].*\)@\2@p'
```

xargs takes output of previous command as input file.

If pattern is Fred.3.20150999999999, first sed will print from matched pattern to filePath= and next sed will extract CDATA in it.

Comment: Hi, this worked great, But the issue is it returns all the CDATA urls. the log file has multiple. So I grep to find the log file name, then to get the URL you need to find the correct section in the log based on the filename and extract the next CDATA only

Comment: Updated the answer to meet your requirement. You can also use below command if your pattern remains same.

`sed -n 's@\(.*CDATA\[\)\(.*\)\(\]\].*\)@\2@p' log/<pattern>*.log`

Comment: Unfortunately it is still grabbing all CDATA URLS, not just the one associated with <filename or Partial filename you are looking for>
The sed would need to find "Renamed to Fred.3.20150999999999" (since that is the filename in the log grep was looking for) and then get the first CDATA URL after that.

Comment: Did you try grep command then piped to sed. If so, can you paste op of only grep

Comment: Yup, I tried the grep piped through sed as above. the grep -Ril only returns the log file name log/test.logging.log
Piping it through sed as above finds the URL for all CDATA in the log the grep found. 
For the grep I can make it grep -Ri -a1 and that outputs the XML for the specific entry I'm after, but sed doesn't like that very much.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, and awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

While your `grep` command may be used to locate the file, the `find` command is quite a bit more flexible and a bit more appropriate. The basic use to locate your log file would be similar to:

```
find /path/to/logdir -type f -name "partial*.log"
```

Which will recursively search under `/path/to/logdir` for a file `-type f` whose name matches the pattern `"partial*.log"`.

Isolating the url can be similar to the other answer, but here using multiple expressions, you can isolate the url with:

```
sed -e 's/^.*CDATA\[\(http[^]]*\).*$/\1/' <logfilename> \
    -e '/^$/'d \
    -e '/^[ \t\n].*$/'d
```

Output:

```
https://<Servername>:<port and path2>&sp=l1703775&sp=l1703775
```

Where the first expression isolates the url itself from within your `<logfilename>`, the second expression suppresses any blank lines and finally, the third, which removes an fragments returned beginning with a [space, tab or newline].

If you can tune your `find` command to reliably return the exact file you need to retrieve the url from, then you can write your `find` and `sed` command together as:

```
sed -e 's/^.*CDATA\[\(http[^]]*\).*$/\1/' \
    $(find /path/to/logdir -type f -name "partial*.log") \
    -e '/^$/'d \
    -e '/^[ \t\n].*$/'d
```

Where you have simply used **command substitution** to replace `<logfilename>` with the `find` command enclosed in `$(...)`.

**Note** there are many different ways to write the `sed` substitution, some probably more elegant that this one, but that is where the power lies in `sed`. Give this a try and let me know if you run into problems. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this worked great, But the issue is it returns the first CDATA url and then the rest of the log. The log file has multiple entries. So I grep to find the log file name, then to get the URL you need to find the correct section in the log based on the filename I used in the grep and extract the next CDATA only.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to think on handling multiple entries a bit more. I'll have more time tonight.

Comment: @telsum to handle multiple occurrence, you can rearrange the commands. try `grep CDATA logfile.log | sed -e 's/^.*CDATA\[\(http[^]]*\).*$/\1/' -e '/^$/'d -e '/^[ \t\n].*$/'d` I don't have a full datafile to test, but that would get each line containing `CDATA` from your logfile and filter each line through the `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks David, yours and the accepted answer taught me a lot about sed, the initial grep was to find the log file name that contained a pattern or literal of a filename inside it and return the log file that contained that. 
Then the next part had to find in said log file from the grep where that pattern or literal occurred and extract the URL from the CDATA directly after it. 
MANY thanks however both answers have opened my eyes to the power of sed.